# How to add a Module in the Footer of OpenERP

Tags: odoo

I am doing configuration of OpenERP. I created a module and it's working fine. I know that the module should be inside of **addons** such as my system path:-

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20130903-231112\Server\server\openerp\addons
```

I got my footer content **Powered by ERP** by **base.xml**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20130903-231112\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\static\src\xml
```

But now I want to add custom module functionality so that some data will always display in the footer. so if user will go in other pages, user will always able to see footer data.